# how to parse yahoo historical csv with Attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

i am a beginner of haskell, how to parse with attoparsec into open array, high array etc

```
module CsvParser (
      Quote (..)
    , csvFile
    , quote
    ) where
import System.IO
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import Data.Time
import System.Locale
import Data.Maybe

data Quote = Quote {
        qTime       :: LocalTime,
        qAsk        :: Double,
        qBid        :: Double,
        qAskVolume  :: Double,
        qBidVolume  :: Double
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

csvFile :: Parser [Quote]
csvFile = do
    q <- many1 quote
    endOfInput
    return q

quote   :: Parser Quote
quote   = do
    time        <- qtime
    qcomma
    ask         <- double
    qcomma
    bid         <- double
    qcomma
    askVolume   <- double
    qcomma
    bidVolume   <- double
    endOfLine
    return $ Quote time ask bid askVolume bidVolume 

qcomma  :: Parser ()
qcomma  = do 
    char ','
    return ()

qtime   :: Parser LocalTime
qtime   = do
    tstring     <- takeTill (\x -> x == ',')
    let time    = parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S%Q" (unpack tstring)
    return $ fromMaybe (LocalTime (fromGregorian 0001 01 01) (TimeOfDay 00 00 00 )) time

--testString :: Text
--testString = "01.10.2012 00:00:00.741,1.28082,1.28077,1500000.00,1500000.00\n" 

quoteParser = parseOnly quote

main = do  
    handle <- openFile "C:\\Users\\ivan\\Downloads\\0005.HK.csv" ReadMode  
    contents <- hGetContents handle  
    let allLines = lines contents
    map (\line -> quoteParser line) allLines
    --putStr contents  
    hClose handle
```

Error message:

```
testhaskell.hs:89:5:
    Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO (Either String Quote)
      Actual type: [Either String Quote]
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      map (\ line -> quoteParser line) allLines
    In the expression:
      do { handle <- openFile
                       "C:\\Users\\ivan\\Downloads\\0005.HK.csv" ReadMode;

           contents <- hGetContents handle;
           let allLines = lines contents;
           map (\ line -> quoteParser line) allLines;
           .... }

testhaskell.hs:89:37:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Text'
    Expected type: [Text]
      Actual type: [String]
    In the second argument of `map', namely `allLines'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      map (\ line -> quoteParser line) allLines
    In the expression:
      do { handle <- openFile
                       "C:\\Users\\ivan\\Downloads\\0005.HK.csv" ReadMode;

           contents <- hGetContents handle;
           let allLines = lines contents;
           map (\ line -> quoteParser line) allLines;
           .... }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse yahoo csv with parsec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211685/how-to-parse-yahoo-csv-with-parsec)

Comment: this question is about using another library attoparsec, i find difficulty to use after read the example, any simple example

Comment: As Michael Snoyman suggestion in that answer, you should be using `csv-conduit`. `csv-conduit` internally uses `attoparsec` to do the parsing tasks. If you are new to Haskell, I would suggest you to start from the basics and then start using these libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [attoparsec-csv](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-csv) package or you can take a look at its [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-csv-0.1.0.1/docs/src/Text-ParseCSV.html) to have some idea on how to write it by yourself.

The code will be like

```
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Text.ParseCSV

main = do
  txt <- T.readFile "file.csv"
  case parseCSV txt of
    Left  err -> error err
    Right csv -> mapM_ (print . mkQuote) csv

mkQuote :: [T.Text] -> Quote
mkQuote = error "Not implemented yet"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with parsec or attoparsec. The line the error message points to is not an `IO` action, so it causes the error when you try to use it as one:

```
main = do  
    handle <- openFile "C:\\Users\\ivan\\Downloads\\0005.HK.csv" ReadMode  
    contents <- hGetContents handle  
    let allLines = lines contents
    map (\line -> quoteParser line) allLines   -- <== This is not an IO action
    --putStr contents  
    hClose handl
```

You ignore the result of the `map` call. You should store it in a variable with `let`, like you do with the result of `lines`.

The second error is because you are trying to use `Text` as `String` which are different types, even though they both represent ordered collections of characters (they also have different internal representations). You can convert between the two types with `pack` and `unpack`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text.html#g:5

Also, you should always explicitly give `main` the type signature `main :: IO ()`. It can sometimes lead to subtle problems if you don't.

As other people have said, though, you should probably use a csv parser package.